# @Around pointcut invokes method two times

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

Sometimes my API throws exception, that server can not process my request. I decided to create AOP aspect which will be reinvoke API call. For example, 5 times and after that throws exception if it still doesn't work.

Please, see my AOP class. This is not a full body, but I hope you will able to understand what is going on:

```
@Aspect
public class RetryRequestExecutor {

    ....

    @Around("@annotation(com.test.RequestRetriable)")
    public Object retryApiRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        int numAttempts = 0;
        ServiceException lastException;
        do {
            numAttempts++;
            try {
                preInvokeLog(point);
                Object retValue = point.proceed();
                postInvokeLog(point);
                return retValue;
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                lastException = handleServiceException(point, numAttempts, e);
            }
        } while (numAttempts <= maxRetries);
        throw lastException;
    }

    ....
}
```

This is my service class:

```
public class UserApiImpl implements UserApi {

    ...

    @Override
    public List<DomainUser> retrieveSuspendedUsers() throws Exception{
        LOG.debug("Retrieving suspended users.");

        ...

        List<DomainUser> users = new ArrayList<DomainUser>(64);
        do {
            //Invoke API. AOP invoke it two times! 
            currentPage = getUsers(retrieveUrl);
                    ...
                    URL nextLink = currentPage.getNextLink();
                    if (nextLink == null){
                        break;
                    }
            ...
        } while (nextLink != null);

        return users;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestRetriable
    public UserFeed getUsers(URL feedUrl) throws Exception {
        return userService.getFeed(feedUrl, UserFeed.class);
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see, I have annotated only `getUsers` method. Method `retrieveSuspendedUsers` is not annotated.

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) configuration looks like this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

Now, when I invoke directly `getUsers` method everything works OK - AOP invokes it only once. But when I invoke `retrieveSuspendedUsers` method - AOP invoke it two times for each page(I retrieve users page by page with page size equal 100). I can see in log below lines:

```
2013-03-11 13:06:40,179 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-1] Invoke API request getUsers with arguments [https://domain.com/user/2.0/]
2013-03-11 13:06:40,180 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-1] Invoke API request getUsers with arguments [https://domain.com/user/2.0/]
2013-03-11 13:06:41,745 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-1] Invoke API request getUsers with arguments [https://domain.com/user/2.0/] finished successfully
2013-03-11 13:06:41,745 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-1] Invoke API request getUsers with arguments [https://domain.com/user/2.0/] finished successfully
```

API call is very time consuming and I want to avoid additional, unnecessary call. How to fix this behavior?

Comment: can you log the caller thread name also

Comment: How is the assignment of `nextLink` handled?

Comment: your advice seems fine, my doubt is somebody is calling `getUsers` twice, if you can log the caller thread we can verify this

Comment: I have add thread name to the log. @matsev - I have added the source code which shows how I retrieve nextlink.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK pointcut interceptions are called both for the `call` and `execution` events of the pointcut advice. You could filter to match only method `execution` in your pointcut:

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(com.test.RequestRetriable)")
```

Comment: You were right! It works! You made my day! Now it invokes only once, even in my "retrieveSuspendedUsers" method. I thought it works only for "execution" by default.